# Find the upper bound of the modulus of a complex polynomial using triangle inequalities

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

The question is to find the upper bound of 
 $$\left|\frac{1}{z^4 + 3z^2 + 2}\right| ,\; where\;|z| = 2,\;z\; \epsilon\; \mathbb{C}$$

My Attempt:

To find its upper bound, finding the lower bound of denominator is sufficient.

Using the triangle inequality $|z_1 \pm z_2| \geqslant ||z_1| - |z_2||$,

$$|z^4 + 3z^2 + 2| \geqslant ||z^4| - |3z^2 + 2||$$ 
$$ \implies |z^4 + 3z^2 + 2| \geqslant |16 - |3z^2 + 2||$$
Now, the greatest value of $|3z^2 + 2|$ is required so that the difference is the smallest.
Using the triangle inequality $|z_1 + z_2| \leqslant |z_1| + |z_2|$,
$$ \implies |z^4 + 3z^2 + 2| \geqslant |16 - (|3z^2| +||2|)| = 2$$

So, this gives the upper bound to be $\frac{1}{2}$.

But, the answer is $\frac{1}{6}$, which I got as well when I solved it geometrically. I have got a hunch that my answer is wrong because I have used two triangle inequalities i.e. using one equality after another leads to an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Put $z^{2}=c$. The problem reduces to one of finding the minimum of $|c^{2}+3c+2|$ for $|c|=4$. Note that $|c^{2}+3c+2|=|(c+2)(c+1)| \geq (4-1)(4-2)=6$.

Hence $\frac 1 6$ is an upper bound for the given function. This bound is attained when $z=2i$.

Comment: But where have you used a triangle inequality?